# Find where file was moved from, using auditctl

Tags: logs

I’m new to auditctl.
I’m trying to monitor a drive to keep a record of renamed, moved from location and destination. However I can only see the destination. E.g:

```
auditctl -w /media/drive -p wa -k drive_key
```

Then:

```
ausearch -k drive_key | aureport -i
```

Are there some flags I can use to see where the file came from and went?

Thanks,
Rob